# Asynchronous or batch processing with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous

I have a .Net application in C# that I am in need of some async processing.  The user will upload a file of PEOPLE records from the aspx page and the system should upload the file, parse the file, load the people in the database, and then move the file out of the initial directory that it was uploaded to.

I don't want the user to have to wait for this, as some files may have thousands of records, and the system could take a while to go through all of them.  I basically want to return a message that says, "Thank you for uploading your file.  The system will process it and send you an email when it has been completed".

I have read about the new async/await keywords, but I'm not sure if that is the route that I should take for this.  I basically just need a button event handler to upload the file and the kick off a "batch" process to finish dealing with the file while returning control to the user on the UI to do whatever else he/she wants to do on the site.

I guess the secondary question would be: Does await return control to the user when used within a button event handler method? If so, then this seems to be a perfect solution for me as it won't block the thread or the user.

Is there a better method or pattern that I should use for this, or is async/await sufficient?

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { UploadFile(...); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess the secondary question would be: Does await return control to the user when used within a button event handler method? If so, then this seems to be a perfect solution for me as it won't block the thread or the user.

`await` does yield to the message loop when used within a button event handler method *in a GUI application*.

> Is there a better method or pattern that I should use for this, or is async/await sufficient?

`async`/`await` will not do this, because [`async` doesn't change the HTTP protocol](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html) - your `await` will just yield to the ASP.NET thread pool (not to the user's browser).

The best way to solve this is to have your ASP.NET page write the file to disk (asynchronously, if possible), and then return the response "we'll email you when it's done".

Then you can have a Win32 service or something that monitors that directory, processes the files, and sends emails. Note that you should use Azure Blobs/Queues instead of the file system if you plan to deploy this to the cloud.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this.  I used the Tasks Library to spawn a separate thread after uploading the file to the file system. The Task loads the file records to a DB table and then processes each record appropriately.  I need to look more into Azure (it is something I would like to do for my application eventually and port the whole thing to the cloud). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use asynchronous page - based on `<%@ Page Async="true" ... %>`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with using ASP.NET/ThreadPool to process the file parsing/database work/email notification you can implement this using an HttpModule/Timer. Use ASP.NET to upload the file and the HttpModule to either monitor file system for new uploads and process the files, or add a database record when file is uploaded and periodically poll the database for new records.

[This article](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) will get you going and also outlines the issues you may face using this method.

If you need something more complicated or your site has a lot of traffic you'd better use a separate process (windows service or scheduled task) for the batch process.

If you require any sample code I can post, but currently using .NET 3.5 rather than 4.0 at the moment.